Double and single delta-function potential well energy similarity
I am working through Griffiths QM at present, and I came across a question that asks me to find

"the bound state energies in the limiting cases (i) $a \to 0$ and (ii) $a \to \infty$ (holding $\alpha$ fixed)"

for the double delta-function potential $V(x)= - \alpha(\delta(x+a)+\delta(x-a))$. After manipulating the time-independent Schrödinger equation for this potential, I have arrived at the transcendental equation
$$
\left( 1- \frac{\hbar^2 \kappa}{m \alpha}\right)^2 = e^{-4 \kappa a},
$$
where $\kappa = \sqrt{-2 m E}/\hbar$. I omit this computation since I think it distracts from my question, but I can include it if needed. Now, the aforesaid limiting cases are obvious, with $a \to 0$ first yielding
$$
E = - \frac{2 m \alpha^2}{\hbar^2}.
$$
I am very willing to accept this intuitively since this is nothing but the bound state energy associated with the single delta-function potential $V(x) = - 2\alpha \delta(x)$; we are, in a manner of speaking, doubling the "strength" of the well when we push these two equally "strong" wells together.
What I am not willing to accept however, is when I take the limit $a \to \infty$, which implies
$$
E = - \frac{m \alpha^2}{2 \hbar^2},
$$
which is exactly the energy associated with the potential $V(x) = -\alpha \delta(x)$. How can it be that two identical potential wells that become increasingly more spatially removed from each other have a bound state energy that increasingly more resembles that of a single delta-function well of equivalent "strength" $\alpha$? Is this just a coincidence, or can I get anything inutitive out of this, like I can with the $a \to 0$ case?

As the two delta peaks are pulled apart, they influence each other less and less. In the limit $a \to \infty$, the bound state energies are completely determined by the bound state energies of a single peak. Maybe it might help you to draw the approximate ground state wavefunction as you pull $a \to \infty$.

Oh, I see. In the limit $a \to \infty$, there is a "traveling" wavefunction that much resembles the solution to the TISE with $V(x)=-\alpha \delta(x)$ and $E=-\frac{m \alpha^2}{2 \hbar^2}$. Thanks! I tried to graph this earlier explicitly (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ztmmqopwox) but was met with a graphing error at $a \approx 89$.
